# Beamer bullet points are lost

Tags: beamer, itemize

I can't make the bullet points appear in my beamer template, but they appear in the contents list.

```
\documentclass[11pt,usenames,xcolor=dvipsnames,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme[named=PineGreen]{structure}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\setbeamercolor{mord}{bg=PineGreen!60!White}

\setbeamerfont{footline}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=5mm,text margin right=5mm} 
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}


\usepackage[justification=justified,format=plain]{caption}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node} % para diagramas
\usepackage{pst-plot} % para representacion de datos funciones, etc
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-coil}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{pgfpages}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{pslatex} 
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcommand{\grad}{$^{\circ} $}
\newcommand{\dint}{\displaystyle\int}
\newcommand{\registered}{\textsuperscript{\textregistered}}
\newcommand{\dsum} {\displaystyle\sum}
\newcommand{\dprod} {\displaystyle\prod}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

\usepackage{textpos} %posicionar texto donde quiera

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\raggedright}{\leftskip=0pt \rightskip=0pt plus 0cm}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\addbibresource{publications.bib}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{highlight}
    {\textbf{#1}}
    {#1}%
} % Pone mi nombre en negritas

\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\tiny} %Las footnotes son en tamaño pequeño


\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\raggedright\insertcaption\par}

%%%%%%%%%%%


\title[Adaptive control using RL]{Adaptive}

\subtitle{\vspace{0.2cm}Doctoral Defense}

\author[K. R]{KR}

\institute [University]{} % (optional)


\date[April, 2023]{\small April 14, 2020}


\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections,sections={1-4}]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections,sections={5-7}]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
  {\color{red!70!black}\inserttocsectionnumber.}~\inserttocsection}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{bg=white,fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{%
  \hspace{1.2em}{\color{red}\rule[0.3ex]{3pt}{3pt}}~\inserttocsubsection\par}

%
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{fg=red}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]
\maketitle
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections,sections={1-4}]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections,sections={5-7}]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{Overview}
\subsection{Context}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Overview}
\framesubtitle{}
\justifying
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Designed to perform many tasks:
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item Rescue
                        \item Healthcare
                    \end{itemize}
                \item Complex variety of capabilities:
                    \begin{itemize} 
                        \item Climbing stairs 
                        \item Avoiding obstacles 
                        \item Jumping 
                        \item Walking on slopes 
                    \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Many approaches have arisen with the aim of improving how robotic devices interact in human-oriented environments 
            \end{itemize}
            \smartdiagramset{planet color=orange!60, distance planet-satellite=1cm}
            \scalebox{0.55}{
            \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{Human-oriented\\ environments, Uncertain \\environments,Presence\\ of external\\ perturbations,Modelling\\ imprecision }
            }
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}

\subsection{General problem statement}
\subsection{Objectives}

\section{Mathematical model}
\subsection{Linear Actuators}
\subsection{Mathematical modeling strategy}
\subsection{Actuator dynamics}
\section{Controller}
\subsection{Problem statement}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `enumerate` or `enumitem` with `beamer`. `beamer` does its own thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There several problems:

- Don't use `enumitem` with beamer, they are incompatible
- If you use `\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{fg=red}` you are replacing the itemize bullet points with the word `fg=red`. To change the colour, you want to use `\setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=red}` instead of overwriting the whole template
- You have to end every frame you start.
- You should clean up your preamble. There are many unnecessary packages

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,usenames,xcolor=dvipsnames,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme[named=PineGreen]{structure}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\setbeamercolor{mord}{bg=PineGreen!60!White}

\setbeamerfont{footline}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=5mm,text margin right=5mm} 
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}


\usepackage[justification=justified,format=plain]{caption}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node} % para diagramas
\usepackage{pst-plot} % para representacion de datos funciones, etc
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-coil}

%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{multicol}

%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{pgfpages}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{pslatex} 
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcommand{\grad}{$^{\circ} $}
\newcommand{\dint}{\displaystyle\int}
\newcommand{\registered}{\textsuperscript{\textregistered}}
\newcommand{\dsum} {\displaystyle\sum}
\newcommand{\dprod} {\displaystyle\prod}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

\usepackage{textpos} %posicionar texto donde quiera

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\raggedright}{\leftskip=0pt \rightskip=0pt plus 0cm}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\addbibresource{publications.bib}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{highlight}
    {\textbf{#1}}
    {#1}%
} % Pone mi nombre en negritas

\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\tiny} %Las footnotes son en tamaño pequeño


\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\raggedright\insertcaption\par}

%%%%%%%%%%%


\title[Adaptive control using RL]{Adaptive}

\subtitle{\vspace{0.2cm}Doctoral Defense}

\author[K. R]{KR}

\institute [University]{} % (optional)


\date[April, 2023]{\small April 14, 2020}


\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections,sections={1-4}]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections,sections={5-7}]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
  {\color{red!70!black}\inserttocsectionnumber.}~\inserttocsection}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{bg=white,fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{%
  \hspace{1.2em}{\color{red}\rule[0.3ex]{3pt}{3pt}}~\inserttocsubsection\par}

%
%\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=red}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]
\maketitle
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections,sections={1-4}]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections,sections={5-7}]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{Overview}
\subsection{Context}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Overview}
\framesubtitle{}
\justifying
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Designed to perform many tasks:
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item Rescue
                        \item Healthcare
                    \end{itemize}
                \item Complex variety of capabilities:
                    \begin{itemize} 
                        \item Climbing stairs 
                        \item Avoiding obstacles 
                        \item Jumping 
                        \item Walking on slopes 
                    \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Many approaches have arisen with the aim of improving how robotic devices interact in human-oriented environments 
            \end{itemize}
            \smartdiagramset{planet color=orange!60, distance planet-satellite=1cm}
            \scalebox{0.55}{
            \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{Human-oriented\\ environments, Uncertain \\environments,Presence\\ of external\\ perturbations,Modelling\\ imprecision }
            }
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\subsection{General problem statement}
\subsection{Objectives}

\section{Mathematical model}
\subsection{Linear Actuators}
\subsection{Mathematical modeling strategy}
\subsection{Actuator dynamics}
\section{Controller}
\subsection{Problem statement}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! Deleting enumitem worked! The rest of the packages are used in the rest of the slides

Comment: Most of the packages are already loaded by beamer automatically. You should really clean up your preamble.